# PowerShell Script to connect with windows -to-windows using New-PSSession working while executing on server, But not working using gitlab CI/CD

Tags: windows, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## **PowerShell Script test.ps1**

This Script contains new-PSSession to Connecting windows server with another windows server using powershell script.
The Script works well by executing on one windows server, But issue occure while executing same script on Gitlab CI/CD
The error is given below gitlab logs :

```
# Set the remote server details
$remoteServer = "[instance-ip]"
$username = "Administrator"
$password = "[password]"

# Set the name of the service, local file path, remote destination path
$serviceName = "bthserv"
$localFilePath = "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe"
$remoteDestination = "C:\Users\Public\Documents"

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $remoteServer -Force

# Create a secure password object
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

# Create a credential object
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword

# Establish a remote PowerShell session
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteServer -Credential $credential -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck)

# Stop the service on the remote server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Param($serviceName)
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName
} -ArgumentList $serviceName

# Copy the file to the remote server
Copy-Item -Path $localFilePath -Destination $remoteDestination -ToSession $session

# Start the service on the remote server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Param($serviceName)
    Start-Service -Name $serviceName
} -ArgumentList $serviceName

# Close the remote session
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

## **Gitlab Error Logs

## **

$ .\test.ps1

```
New-PSSession : [0.0.0.0](instance ip) Connecting to remote server 0.0.0.0 failed with the following error message : 
WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x8009030d occurred while using Negotiate 
authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or 
use HTTPS transport.
```

I want to Execute powershell script on gilab cicd.
If you have faced same use case please reply

Comment: Change `$username = "Administrator"` to `$username = "userdomain\Administrator"` or `$username = ".\Administrator"`

Comment: there is a condition not to use domain only ip

Comment: If `Administrator` is the local admin account on the machine, then use either `".\Administrator"` or `"machineName\Administrator"`